# 596 Service Not Found in JSON Parsing for Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, json

I am parsing data using JSON parsing. The ConnectionDidFinishLoading Function is :-

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
if (connection==conn1) {`[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self requestFinished:theXML];}}
```

The error shown for theXML is 596 Service Not Found. Though the webdata being fetched is round 30 bytes. Any Idea what this error means ?

Comment: could you give the service link ?

Comment: http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=ne8mz72zfcjkj76ycvazh9u8&q=The+Avengers&page_limit=5 Abdullah Md. Zubair